# Filter list by index match vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two lists. The first list is in a carousel and the second list are details of each displayed card. Right now I am able to get the current index of the displayed card in the carousel into a data object `cardIndexShow` so if I swipe to the next the index changes from 0 to 1 and so on. Now for the second list with an array of details, I want to only show the detail in which its index matches with the first list index. So basically index(0) of card only shows detail with index(0). If I swipe to the next which changes the card index to 1, the details list changes too to the detail with index 1.

For my second list I have

```
 <div v-for="(cardTransactions, index) in card_transactions_filtered" v-bind:key="index" ">
          <p>{{ cardTransactions.detail }}</p>
</div>
```

In the computed property I have this with `card_transactions` being the main list

```
computed:{
      card_transactions_filtered(){
        return this.card_transactions.filter...
      // how to proceed from here
      }

    },
```

I just want to show `this.card_transactions` where its index matches the
value in `this.cardIndexShow`

Comment: The second parameter of the filter function is the index of the array, you should probably use it. Something like: `this.card_transactions.filter((card, index) => index === this.cardIndexShow)`.

Answer (score 0):

store `cardIndexShow` in data and make computed prop getDetails or something

```
computed:{
      card_details(){
        return this.card_transactions[this.cardIndexShow];
      }
    },
```

and in template

```
 <p>{{ card_details }}</p>
```

Comment: this answer is actually better if you don't need to do any transformation in your object, you should make it the "accepted" one